# OperaDriver fails to start

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, opera, operadriver

There was an update last week for Opera browser. Since then it stopped working. It opens the browser and shows 'data:,' in the URL and throws webdriver exception. Is Opera 41 compatible with selenium 2.53.1?

Exception thrown is:

```
Result Message: Initialization method SDTestAutomation.HomePage_Tests.Init threw exception. OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:64865/session timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out..
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Opera.OperaDriver..ctor(String operaDriverDirectory, OperaOptions options)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Opera.OperaDriver..ctor(String operaDriverDirectory)
at SmartDebitTestFramework.Drivers.Initialize(String browser)
```

Browser initialisation is straight forward.

```
driver = new OperaDriver(path of the driver);
```

Tried selenium 3 as well but no luck. Got the same exception.

Comment: There is no way to automate the latest opera driver. :)

Comment: @QualityProducts Why is that? Do you have any source which confirms this. Is downgrading the only option?

Comment: @QualityProducts Can we stop Opera upgrading automatically.  I didn't find an option in settings to stop updating automatically. Thanks.

Comment: You go to Opera's installation folder and find the folder with the number of the latest build. Inside it you will find the file 'opera_autoupdate.exe'.

Comment: @QualityProducts Thank you. What version are you running your tests on. I could successfully run on previous version that is V40. Need to try whether it still works now.

Comment: Try on V41. Thats the latest version. Im running on 38.  :)

Comment: V41 doesn't work. I'm on 41 so with your suggestion thought of downgrading but I couldn't stop it from upgrading. We have network support, and one guy tried for 2hrs and he couldn't make it stop. The version he downgraded is Opera 30 which is 11 versions old. I asked him for 38 or 39, he said I have to try. Hope he finds a solution. Deleting the update.exe didn't help.

Comment: Yeah! So, ur problem solved then. :)

Comment: @QualityProducts With the latest version of Opera ie. V41, selenium doesn't work. I need to downgrade Opera which is so hard. Whatever we do, it is again getting updated to V41 :(

Answer (score 0):

After downgrading Opera to version 40, I'm able to run my test suite as before.

Comment: Q: How did you downgrade to version 40 (I've got the same problem)

Comment: @Stormcloud I got help from network guys. You need to delete autoupdate.exe file from opera installer folder under program files and then download the version you required.

Comment: I'll give that ago. Thanks for your help