# selenium's webdriver.Opera() gives error: session not created exception from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, opera, operadriver

I'm trying to open url in Opera browser using selenium.
I downloaded operadriver 0.2.2 from here https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases

Here is python code `opera.py`:

```
#! coding: utf:8
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Opera()
driver.get('example.com')
driver.close()
```

But it gives me an error:

```
$ python opera.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "opera.py", line 25, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Opera()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/opera/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    service_log_path=service_log_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/opera/webdriver.py", line 52, in __init__
    service_log_path=service_log_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"2168.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: Opera with embedded Chromium 54.0.2840.99)
  (Driver info: OperaDriver=0.2.0 (ba47709ed9e35ce26dbd960fb5d75be104290d96),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.0 x86_64)
```

When I using `webdriver.Chrome()` insted of Opera everything works.

How could I solve this problem with `webdriver.Opera()`?

Comment: Is the driver in PATH?

Comment: @Leva7 yes, I've placed operadriver to `/usr/local/bin/`

Comment: @pupadupa, try to use up-to-date `operadriver v0.2.2` from https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases

Comment: @Andersson yes, I'm using latest one (v0.2.2)

Comment: OperaChromiumDriver is a WebDriver implementation derived from ChromeDriver, also make sure your Chromedriver is the latest version. https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Comment: @jinksPadlock yes  I'm using latest one ChromeDriver 2.25

Comment: What version of Opera are you using? If it's latest version download to V 40 or below. I had the same issue and that is the only solution found. For reference, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419781/operadriver-fails-to-start) is my Question in SO. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Sudeepthi I'm using latest version. Thanks, I will try to install V40