# Issues with latest version of Opera and it's driver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, opera, operadriver

Based on my previous [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419781/operadriver-fails-to-start), I downgraded Opera to V40, since yesterday I'm having issues with button clicks and switching to iframe etc..

So I upgraded Opera to v44 and downloaded latest version of Operadriver v2.27 for windows 64 from [here](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases).

Initialising driver:

```
static string path = @"C:\Drivers";
public static IWebDriver _driverInstance = null;
_driverInstance = new OperaDriver(path);
```

Intially I got an exception

```
Result Message: Initialization method HomePage_Tests.Init threw exception. System.InvalidOperationException: System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: cannot find Opera binary
(Driver info: OperaDriver=2.27 (f61056e560d197467fd6d27c7fbd7fea572fe8bd),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64).
Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Opera.OperaDriver..ctor(String operaDriverDirectory, OperaOptions options)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Opera.OperaDriver..ctor(String operaDriverDirectory)
at SmartDebitTestFramework.Drivers.Initialize(String browser)
```

Then changed the code as

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Opera();
OperaOptions options = new OperaOptions();
options.BinaryLocation = path;
capabilities.SetCapability(OperaOptions.Capability, options);
_driverInstance = new OperaDriver(options);
```

Now the exception is:

```
Result Message: Initialization method HomePage_Tests.Init threw exception. System.InvalidOperationException: System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: Opera failed to start
(Driver info: OperaDriver=2.27 (f61056e560d197467fd6d27c7fbd7fea572fe8bd),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64).
Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Opera.OperaDriver..ctor(OperaDriverService service, OperaOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Opera.OperaDriver..ctor(OperaOptions options)
at SmartDebitTestFramework.Drivers.Initialize(String browser)
```

Can you please help with correct setting for making Opera work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this in such way:

`//Opera settings
OperaDriverService service = OperaDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@""); \\path to OD
OperaOptions options = new OperaOptions();
options.BinaryLocation = @""; \\path to my Opera browser
WebDriver = new OperaDriver(service, options);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still getting "Opera failed to start" exception for the last line in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try  it like this

```
capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "operablink");
capabilities.setCapability("opera.binary", "/path/to/your/opera");
capabilities.Platform = new Platform(PlatformType.Windows);
_webDriver = new OperaDriver(capabilities);
```

On your node:

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "operablink",
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 1,
  "port": 5555,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://localhost:4444",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
}
```

Comment: '_webDriver = new OperaDriver(capabilities);' throws an error. OperaDriver is not accepting capabilities as a parameter.